# How improve vertical spacing between rows of table?

Tags: tables, formatting, booktabs, vertical-spacing

I built the following table through the help of [this webtool](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/) but I'm not satisfied about the vertical spacing between the rows. Can you show how to improve it and reduce a little bit the size of the table? Is convenient to use the `multirow` command? If yes, how to implement it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\sisetup{
    round-mode=places,
    uncertainty-mode = separate,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Summary of the \glspl{acronym:NEO} classification \cite{web:CNEOS:NEO:Basics:NEO:Groups}.}
\label{tab:NEOs:classification}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Group}} & \textbf{Definition} & \textbf{Description} \\ \midrule
NECs & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}$q \leq \SI{1.3}{\astronomicalunit}$ \\  $P  < \SI{200}{\years}$\end{tabular} & Near-Earth Comets \\[0.35cm]
NEAs & $q \leq \SI{1.3}{au}$ & Near-Earth Asteroids \\[0.35cm] 
Atiras & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}$a< \SI{1.0}{\astronomicalunit}$\\ $Q \leq \SI{0.983}{\astronomicalunit}$\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\glspl{acronym:NEA} whose orbits are contained entirely with the\\ orbit of the Earth (named after asteroid 163693 Atira).\end{tabular} \\[0.35cm] 
Atens & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}$a< \SI{1.0}{\astronomicalunit}$\\ $Q > \SI{0.983}{\astronomicalunit} $\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Earth-crossing \glspl{acronym:NEA} with semi-major axes \\ smaller than Earth's (named after asteroid 2062 Aten).\end{tabular} \\[0.35cm]  
Apollos & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}$a> \SI{1.0}{\astronomicalunit}$\\ $q< \SI{1.017}{\astronomicalunit}$\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Earth-crossing \glspl{acronym:NEA} with semi-major axes larger \\ than Earth's (named after asteroid 1862 Apollo).\end{tabular} \\[0.35cm]  
Amors & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}$a> \SI{1.0}{\astronomicalunit}$\\ $ 1.017 < q < 1.3 \SI{}{\astronomicalunit} $\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Earth-approaching \glspl{acronym:NEA} with orbits exterior to \\ Earth's but interior to Mars' (named after asteroid 1221 Amor).\end{tabular} \\[0.35cm] 
PHAs & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}$MOID \leq \SI{0.05}{\astronomicalunit}$\\ $H \leq \num{22.0}$\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Potentially Hazardous Asteroids: \glspl{acronym:NEA} whose \\ \gls{acronym:MOID} with \\ the Earth is 0.05 au or less and whose absolute \\ magnitude ($H$) is 22.0 or brighter.\end{tabular} \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can adjust the row spacing using `\arraystretch` (macro scale factor), but it will have no effect in the outer tabular for values <2.  I would use an m or M column (see array and tabularx manuals) for the third column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need for `multirow`.

I would define the last column as paragraph-like and let latex decide on line breaks. For example, I applied `m{<len>}` with the fixed length and a left-alignment because your example is vertically centred.

I think it's better to use `arraystretch` to change the spacing between rows. The disadvantage is it becomes asymmetrical when factors are larger and needs adjustments. In this case, only the first row requires an extra strut (via `\rule...`).

I also created a convenient macro to add multiple lines with `arraystretch` defined as 1, so the internal row spacing remains default--of course, this is subject to change.

Here's the table

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
% \usepackage{csvsimple}
% \usepackage{graphicx}

\sisetup{
    round-mode=places,
    uncertainty-mode = separate,
}
\DeclareSIUnit\years{Y}    % \years is not defined 
\newcommand\glspl[1]{#1}   % Here: error compiling the code, hence this macro
\newcommand\gls[1]{#1}     % Here: error compiling the code, hence this macro
\NewDocumentCommand\TB{O{l}m}{%
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}#1@{}}#2\end{tabular}}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.85}
    \centering
    \caption{Summary of the \protect\glspl{acronym:NEO} classification \cite{web:CNEOS:NEO:Basics:NEO:Groups}.}
    \label{tab:NEOs:classification}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}ll >{\RaggedRight}m{8cm}@{}}
        \toprule
        \rule[-0.7\normalbaselineskip]{0pt}{1.8\normalbaselineskip}%
        \textbf{Group}
        & \textbf{Definition}
        & \textbf{Description}\\
        \midrule
        NECs
        & \TB{
            $q\leq \qty{1.3}{\astronomicalunit}$\\
            $P < \qty{200}{\years}$
        }
        & Near-Earth Comets \\
        NEAs
        & $q \leq \qty{1.3}{au}$
        & Near-Earth Asteroids \\
        Atiras
        & \TB{
            $a< \qty{1.0}{\astronomicalunit}$\\
            $Q \leq \qty{0.983}{\astronomicalunit}$
        }
        & \glspl{acronym:NEA} whose orbits are contained entirely with the orbit of the Earth (named after asteroid 163693 Atira). \\
        Atens
        & \TB{
            $a< \qty{1.0}{\astronomicalunit}$\\
            $Q > \qty{0.983}{\astronomicalunit} $
        } 
        & Earth-crossing \glspl{acronym:NEA} with semi-major axes smaller than Earth's (named after asteroid 2062 Aten). \\
        Apollos
        & \TB{
            $a> \qty{1.0}{\astronomicalunit}$\\
            $q< \qty{1.017}{\astronomicalunit}$
        }
        & Earth-crossing \glspl{acronym:NEA} with semi-major axes larger than Earth's (named after asteroid 1862 Apollo). \\ 
        Amors
        & \TB{
            $a> \qty{1.0}{\astronomicalunit}$\\
            $1.017 < q < 1.3 \qty{}{\astronomicalunit}$}
        & Earth-approaching \glspl{acronym:NEA} with orbits exterior to Earth's but interior to Mars' (named after asteroid 1221 Amor). \\
        PHAs
        & \TB{%
            $MOID \leq \qty{0.05}{\astronomicalunit}$\\
            $H \leq \num{22.0}$
        }
        & Potentially Hazardous Asteroids: \glspl{acronym:NEA} whose \gls{acronym:MOID} with the Earth is 0.05 au or less and whose absolute magnitude ($H$) is 22.0 or brighter. \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Another solution is `tabularx` with `X`-column-type to avoid having to search for the accurate column width. By default, `tabularx` defines `X` as `p{}` but in the table above it may not work. The macro: `tabularxcolumn` is provided to redefine `X`, e.g.

```
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}m{#1}}
```

Comment: Since I use a complex modular overleaf project with many `.tex` files, can you show how to "embed" the preamble inside the `table` environment?

Comment: @Giuseppe It's ok to move the whole blocks of `\newcommand`, `\NewDocumentCommand`, or `\DeclareSIUnit` inside an environment, e.g. `table` in a separate file. You will just make them locally visible only within this environment. Other `table`s can't use those macros unless you repeat the definitions. It's important the definitions are placed before the first use!

Answer (score 1):

I would use `\tblr` of `tabularray` package and redefine `\TB` style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\sisetup{
    round-mode=places,
    uncertainty-mode = separate,
}
\DeclareSIUnit\years{Y}    % \years is not defined
\newcommand\glspl[1]{#1}   % Here: error compiling the code, hence this macro
\newcommand\gls[1]{#1}     % Here: error compiling the code, hence this macro
\NewDocumentCommand\TB{m}{\begin{array}{@{}l @{}}#1\end{array}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\caption{Summary of the \protect\glspl{acronym:NEO} classification \cite{web:CNEOS:NEO:Basics:NEO:Groups}.}
\label{tab:NEOs:classification}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={@{} l Q[l, mode=math] X[l,m] @{}},
                 row{1} ={font=\bfseries, mode=text}
                 }
        \toprule
Group   &   Definition  
            & Description                           \\
        \midrule
NECs    & \TB{q\leq \qty{1.3}{au}\\
              P < \qty{200}{\years}}
            & Near-Earth Comets                     \\
NEAs    &   q \leq \qty{1.3}{au} 
            & Near-Earth Asteroids                  \\
Atiras  & \TB{a <    \qty{1.0}{au}   \\
              Q \leq \qty{0.983}{au}}
            & \glspl{acronym:NEA} whose orbits are contained entirely with the orbit of the Earth (named after asteroid 163693 Atira).                          \\
Atens   & \TB{a < \qty{1.0}{\astronomicalunit}  \\
              Q > \qty{0.983}{\astronomicalunit}}
        & Earth-crossing \glspl{acronym:NEA} with semi-major axes smaller than Earth's 
        (named after asteroid 2062 Aten).           \\
Apollos & \TB{a> \qty{1.0}{\astronomicalunit}   \\
              q< \qty{1.017}{\astronomicalunit}}
        & Earth-crossing \glspl{acronym:NEA} with semi-major axes larger than Earth's 
        (named after asteroid 1862 Apollo).         \\
Amors   & \TB{a> \qty{1.0}{\astronomicalunit}   \\
              1.017 < q < 1.3 \qty{}{\astronomicalunit}}
        & Earth-approaching \glspl{acronym:NEA} with orbits exterior to Earth's but interior to Mars' (named after asteroid 1221 Amor). \\
PHAs    & \TB{MOID \leq \qty{0.05}{\astronomicalunit} \\
              H \leq \num{22.0}}
        & Potentially Hazardous Asteroids: \glspl{acronym:NEA} whose \gls{acronym:MOID} with the Earth is 0.05 au or less and whose absolute magnitude ($H$) is 22.0 or brighter. \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The code `\\[0.35cm]` at the end of each line gives a newline with a spacing of 3,5 mm. You can just reduce that number - or even remove the whole brackets. :)

Comment: I noticed that the command `\\[0.35cm]` does not produce an equal spacing among all the rows (Compare the first two rows with the others). Hence I would want a way to set spacing with a single command, without giving a command for each row.